# How can I get this a symbol, ā to show up on my web site?

Tags: html

How can I get this a symbol, ā to show up on my web site?

it is for http://www.ohanamakamae.org/
and all the other symbols work, just not the ā.

I hope someone can help, I am working in Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 2):

Put this instead of the character into your HTML: `&#x0101;`
If you need it capitalized, `&#x0100;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the correct character encoding for your page, you will not have to escape ā at all (look for the meta tag below):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
How can I get this a symbol, ā to show up on my web site?
</body>
</html>
```

More on [character encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.  I could do it for all sorts of letters in the English alphabet.

I tested this IE 9 only.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            hi
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            a&#x304; b&#x304; c&#x304; d&#x304; e&#x304; f&#x304; g&#x304;
            h&#x304; i&#x304; j&#x304; k&#x304; l&#x304; m&#x304; n&#x304;
            o&#x304; p&#x304; q&#x304; r&#x304; s&#x304; t&#x304; u&#x304;
            v&#x304; w&#x304; x&#x304; y&#x304; z&#x304;
        </p>
        <p>
            A&#x304; B&#x304; C&#x304; D&#x304; E&#x304; F&#x304; G&#x304;
            H&#x304; I&#x304; J&#x304; K&#x304; L&#x304; M&#x304; N&#x304;
            O&#x304; P&#x304; Q&#x304; R&#x304; S&#x304; T&#x304; U&#x304;
            V&#x304; W&#x304; X&#x304; Y&#x304; Z&#x304;
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```